# Logarithmic irrational inequality

Tags: inequality, logarithms

From the following inequality:
$$\left({\sqrt{x^2-4x+3}}+1\right)\cdot(\log_5x-1)+\frac{1}{x}\cdot\left(\sqrt{8x-2x^2-6}+1\right)\le0$$
I found the domain:
$x^2-4x+3\ge0$ and $8x-2x^2-6\ge0$ and $x\gt0$ from which I obtained $x\in(0,+\infty)$
But from there I can't seem to do anything else. Is this domain even correct and where do I start from here?

Comment: Don't forget that the logarithm (over the reals) cannot have a negative argument, so you also have that $x-1 > 0$ as a result. That said, is that all you need to do, determine the domain?

Comment: Do you see that $8x-2x^2-6 = -2(x^2-4x+3)=-2(x-1)(x-3)$?

Comment: Well, not really, i don't know how to start solving it. I multiplied the factors but i don't know what to do next. Also thanks for reminding me about x-1>0

Comment: so i can factorise?

Comment: This means that both root expressions have only $x=1$ and $x=3$ as common domain. What does this tell you about the domain of the whole expression?

Comment: That it can be either x=1 or x=3?

Comment: So it is. :-) ...

Comment: Alright. Thank you so much!